# Why child process returns exit status = 32512 in unix?

Tags: c++, c, shell, unix, posix

In my program I'm executing given command and getting result (log, and exit status). Also my program have to support shell specific commands (i.e. commands which contains shell specific characters ~(tild),|(pipe),*). But when I try to run `sh -c ls | wc` in my home directory via my program it failed and its exit status was 32512, also in stderr stream `"sh: ls | wc: command not found"` was printed.

But the interesting thing is that the command `sh -c ls | wc` works correct if I run it in shell.

What is the problem? Or more preferable how can I run shell specific commands via my program (i.ec which command with which parameters should I run)?

The code part bellow is in child part after fork(). It executs the command.

`tokenized_command` is `std::vector<std::string>` where in my case `"sh", "-c", "ls", "|", "wc"` are stored, also I have tried to store there `"sh", "-c", "\"ls | wc\""` but result is same. `command` is `char *` where full command line is stored.

```
        boost::shared_array<const char *> bargv(new const char *[tokenized_command.size() + 1]);
        const char **argv = bargv.get();
        for(int i = 0; i < tokenized_command.size(); ++i)
        {
            argv[i] = tokenized_command[i].c_str();
            printf("argv[%d]: %s\n", i, argv[i]); //trace
        }
        argv[tokenized_command.size()] = NULL;

        if(execvp(argv[0], (char * const *)argv) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute command %s: %s", command, strerror(errno));
            _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
```

P.S.

I know that using `system(command)` instead `execvp` can solve my problem. But `system()` waits until command is finished, and this is not good enough for my program. And also I'm sure that in implementation of `system()` one of exec-family functions is used, so the problem can be solved via `exec` as well, but I don't know how.

Comment: Please give some code showing how you are running the shell command, and collecting the result and exit status.

Comment: I didn't see anything related to the `c` or `c++` tags so I removed them.

Comment: I have added something related to the `c` and `c++`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`execvp` takes a path to an executable, and arguments with which to launch that executable. It doesn't take bourne shell commands.

`ls | wc` is a bourne shell command (among others), and it can't be broken down into the path to an executable and some arguments due to the use of a pipe. This means it can't be executed using `execvp`.

To execute a bourne shell command using `execvp`, one has to execute `sh` and pass `-c` and the command for arguments.

```
char *const argv[] = {
    "sh",
    "-c", "ls | wc",  // Command to execute.
    NULL
};

execvp(argv[0], argv)
```

---

**About your attempts**

You apparently tried

```
char *const argv[] = {
    "sh",
    "-c", "ls",  // Command to execute.
    "|",         // Stored in called sh's $0.
    "wc",        // Stored in called sh's $1.
    NULL
};
```

That would be the same as bourne shell command `sh -c ls '|' wc`.

And both are very different than shell command `sh -c ls | wc`. That would be

```
char *const argv[] = {
    "sh",
    "-c", "sh -c ls | wc",  // Command to execute.
    NULL
};
```

You seem to think `|` and `wc` are passed to the `sh`, but that's not the case at all. `|` is a special character which results in a pipe, not an argument.

---

**About the exit code**

The following is the format of the exit code:

```
Bits 15-8 = Exit code.
Bit     7 = 1 if a core dump was produced.
Bits  6-0 = Signal number that killed the process.
```

You got 32512, or 0x7F00.

So it didn't die from a signal, a core dump wasn't produced, and it exited with code 127 (0x7F).

What 127 means is unclear, which is why it should accompanied by an error message. You tried to execute program `ls | wc`, but there is no such program.

Comment: No I'm getting error message. Sorry that I havn't put it here.

`sh: ls | wc: command not found` this is the message/

Comment: @Mihran Hovsepyan, you are trying to execute the file named "`ls | wc`" rather than the bourne shell command "`ls | wc`". If you want to execute a bourne shell command, you need to launch a bourne shell and pass it the command. `sh -c 'ls | wc'`.

Comment: I don't wan't lunch shell. I wan't run shell specific commands from my program.

Comment: @Mihran Hovsepyan. It's not clear what you mean by that. If you mean you want to avoid running a shell, then you simply can't execute `ls | wc`. If you mean you want to make the shell configurable, I don't really see the point, but nothing's stopping you.

Comment: @Mihran Hovsepyan. If you wanted to avoid running a shell, you'll need to launch two processes (`ls` in one, `wc` in other), creating a pipe between them in the process. You'll also have to manage the termination of two processes instead of one. It might even be easier to implement the functionality you want from `ls` and `wc` yourself.

Comment: I want avoid running a shell. Now re: first comment `ls | wc` wouldn't work, because `ls` doesn't take as argument `|` and `wc`. But I think that `sh` takes as arguments `-c` and `'ls | wc'`. re: second comment I want my program can run everything which is possible in shell `ls | wc` is just example.

Comment: Yes @Mihran Hovsepyan, `sh -c 'ls | wc'`, runs the bourne shell (`sh`) and passes arguments `-c` and a shell command (`ls | wc`).

Comment: Yes @ikegami. I'm talking about same. Then why this doesn't work?

Comment: @Mihran Hovsepyan, I've updated to my post. It should now answer all your questions.

Comment: You have `"NULL"` instead of `NULL`. Just sayin'

Answer (score 1):

You should execute `sh -c 'ls | wc'`.

Option `-c` expects a command in form of string. In shell of course it is working, because there is no difference between spawning `ls` and redirecting output to `wc` and launching `ls | wc` in separate shell.

Comment: Actually, it was probably spawning a separate shell to run `ls` and also spawning a `wc` to receive its output.

Comment: Yes, I know, I just didn't underlined it.