# pthead_create causes error status 0x7F00

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, pthreads

I'm trying to get a pthread example to run on my Windows 10 64-bit machine

I'm compiling using the most recent version of cygwin (64-bit), compiling the code as

```
gcc thread.c -pthread -o main.exe
```

which compiles with no error. thread.c looks like so:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void *worker_thread(void *arg)
{
    printf("This is worker_thread()\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    int a = fork();


    if (a == 0) {
        printf("child a=%d\n", a);
        pthread_t my_thread;

        int ret =  pthread_create(&my_thread, NULL, &worker_thread, NULL);

        printf("ret = %d\n", ret);

    } else {
        printf("parent a=%d\n", a);

        int status;

        wait(&status);

        printf("status = 0x%X (%d)\n", status, status);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

On my machine, the output looks like so:

```
parent a=10868
child a=0
status = 0x7F00 (32512)
```

which is happening because pthread_create is causing my code to exit.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638321/why-child-process-returns-exit-status-32512-in-unix), this error means:

"It didn't die from a signal, a core dump wasn't produced, and it exited with code 127 (0x7F).

What 127 means is unclear, which is why it should accompanied by an error message."

On my windows 8 64-bit machine, the code runs as expected, with the same build of cygwin (64-bit) installed, and returns this output.

```
parent a=26744
child a=0
ret = 0
this is worker_thread()
status 0x0 (0)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Win10 64bit / Cygwin 64 bit -- ran as expected

Comment: Well, at least it's not an OS problem, probably

Comment: You aren't joining or detaching on the created thread, which is undefined behavior (I assume you'd want to join on it in this situation). Try adding `pthread_join(my_thread, NULL);` after you create the thread and see what happens.

Comment: The child does not process after the `pthread_create` call, putting anything there is never reached because the child silently crashes.